# Is there a way to serve static resources with Traefik?

Tags: static, bundle, traefik

I'd like to serve static ressources such as images, js bundles, html pages... with [Traefik](https://traefik.io/) like I was able to do with nginx

```
# nginx config
server {
    root /www/data;

    location ~ \.js {
        root /www/bundles;
    }
}
```

Many thanks
Cheers

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Traefik doesn't serve static files (it's a not a web server it's a reverse proxy/load balancer).

You must use a container, which contains a web server with your files.

Comment: So what is solution when I want to serve static files with nginx? 1) create 1 traefik for ssl 2) create nginx for serving static ?

Comment: I would like to knock out nginx entirely for our django deploys. I thought Traefik might be a nice replacement there.

Answer (score 15):

To extend the answer related to how files can be served:

If you are already serving files with nginx and want to migrate to Traefik you can still have nginx serving static files behind Traefik. I do this myself in hobby projects running docker standalone on a VM.

The best way is probably still to use containers/buckets such as S3 or Swift for static files as it will offload the traffic to the application server and provide a single location for these files (makes things easy when clustering) .. but if you don't have a lot of traffic and use a very simple setup, the nginx way is more than fine.

The issue around static files was discussed here : https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/4240

Comment: I wonder however why S3 is called a "container". Word "container" is commonly associated with Docker containers and this may make confusion.

Comment: "Bucket" would  probably fit better for s3

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. I think I'm conceptually missing something. It sounds like I can place my static files i.e. directory produced from `npm run build` on a CDN? I'm using DigitalOcean Spaces CDN. Do I literally just upload that build folder to the CDN to serve the static files and just use Traefik for the API - no Nginx? If so, how does the initial request to my server know to route to the CDN for the static files?